# Force Azure DevOps Pull Request update after Manually Update SonarQube issue as Won't Fix

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, pull-request, azure-repos

I've manually closed a SonarQube issue as Resolved (Won't Fix) and now the Quality Gate in SonarQube is showing as Passed.  However, the pull request in Azure DevOps is still showing the SonarQube Quality Gate as failing.  I asked my team lead how I could update the PR to show the correct SonarQube status and he said the only way was to trigger a new PR build (via requeuing the build in the PR).  Is this really the only way to update the Quality Gate info in the Azure DevOps PR?

I'd prefer to avoid this if I can since our builds take about 15-20 minutes.  I'm hoping there is some way I can update the PR Quality Gate status from SonarQube in a minute or two.

Comment: From looking at the  [Evaluations GET REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), devops provides API to get pull request's checks, but no update function. On the devops side, I am afraid PR checks update is not supported at the present.